# using params[] wih ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectdatasource

My EF insert method is defined as follows:

```
public void Add(params T[] items)
```

How can it be used with ObjectDataSource to insert objects?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it "how to loop over a params array"? Do you know about `foreach()`?

Comment: by writing its body? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.insertmethod(v=vs.110).aspx), the insert method for an `ObjectDataSource` is designed to call a method that has parameters for each *value* of the item being inserted, not the item itself (let alone an *array* of items).

I would either add an overload to your repository that accepts the value for a single item (and perhaps calls `Add`), or add a mapper somewhere that maps the values to a new item and calls your `Add` method.